# How to change "Facilititor Account Test Store" from which is generate by sendbox paypal account in magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal, sandbox

I have a magento site and using paypal (sandbox) as a payment method. After order confirmation pdf is generated with the following text in pdf printout
" Facilitator Account Test Store". So How can I change this text.

Please guide me for this solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

"Facilitator Account Test Store" , this is the by default business name of default sandbox account . You need to change the business name by logging into your sandbox account and then go to Profile--> My business Info --> Business Name Change  . Here you can put the new business name as per your requirement .

Step 1 :

[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Comment: Where is that and what account to use? `sandbox.paypal.com` or `paypal.com`? Real PP account or sandbox account created manually?